# How Can I link two mysql tables?

Tags: php, mysql, linux, ubuntu

is there a way to link two mysql tables so that a query to update one table will automatically add an entry to another table, for instance.  whenever I update the `radcheck.UserName` table it will automatically add the same entry to `userinfo.username` (adding any default values as the entries are added)?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/triggers.html

Comment: Using a TRIGGER would help.

Comment: [pt-table-sync](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-table-sync.html) - Synchronize MySQL table data efficiently.

Answer (score -1):

CREATE
    TRIGGER `table_name` AFTER INSERT 
    ON `table` 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

```
    IF NEW.deleted THEN
        SET @changetype = 'DELETE';
    ELSE
        SET @changetype = 'NEW';
    END IF;

    INSERT INTO audit (table_id, changetype) VALUES (NEW.id, @changetype);

END$$
```